# How to pass a Javascript Array via JQuery Post so that all its contents are accessible via the PHP $_POST array?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How can I pass a Javascript Array via JQuery Post so that all its contents are accessible via the PHP $_POST array?

Please show an example of code that would do the trick.

Thanks!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you want to pass a JavaScript object/hash (ie. an associative array in PHP) then you would do:

```
$.post('/url/to/page', {'key1': 'value', 'key2': 'value'});
```

If you wanna pass an actual array (ie. an indexed array in PHP) then you can do:

```
$.post('/url/to/page', {'someKeyName': ['value','value']});
```

If you want to pass a JavaScript array then you can do:

```
$.post('/url/to/page', {'someKeyName': variableName});
```

Answer (score 25):

This is fairly straightforward.  In your JS, all you would do is this or something similar:

```
var array = ["thing1", "thing2", "thing3"];

var parameters = {
  "array1[]": array,
  ...
};

$.post(
  'your/page.php',
  parameters
)
.done(function(data, statusText) {
    // This block is optional, fires when the ajax call is complete
});
```

In your php page, the values in array form will be available via `$_POST['array1']`.

**references**

- [jQuery post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
- [jQuery ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 8):

Here it goes an example:

```
$.post("test.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"] });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But what if the array is in a Javascript variable?

Comment: var choices = ["Jon", "Susan"];
$.post("test.php", { 'choices[]': choices });

Comment: @Rui, why is the single quotation around `choices[]` ? where is the rule about it in the site of the js or jquery authority please ?

Comment: when i was sending `var choiseArr=[];choiseArr=[0]='Jon'; choiseArr=[1]='Susan'; $.post("test.php", { 'choices': choiseArr }); it sends request but not as an array but as choices two times. so i was getting value susan only. your answer helped. saved lots of time.. thanks... :)

Answer (score 1):

I think we should sent in this format

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$.post('/controller/MyAction', $.param({ data: array }, true), function(data) {});
```

Its already mentioned in 
[Pass array to mvc Action via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489461/pass-array-to-mvc-action-via-ajax)

It worked for me