# How to pass array through ajax to a php file?

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery

I have a form that would pass ids of some items to `ajax`  and i need to update all the rows with those arrays with the updated datas.
I have to use `ajax` to accomplish this.
The ids are generated through mysql queries and I passed it to an array.
So it is already an array and how do i change to javascript-processable(if that's a word) data and change it back to php array.
Here's my code
this is how to make the array

```
foreach($items as $item){
    $item_arr[]=$item['id']
}
```

and I pass the array to an input field to fetch to ajax

```
<input type="hidden" id="myid" value="<?php echo json_encode($item_arr); ?>"/>
```

and

```
    $myid=$("#myid").val();
    $.ajax({
    url:"myurl.php",
    data:{myid:myid},
})
```

this is returning I don't know what!!Please help
this is my first try with this kind of conversion of array..Please bear with me

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571646/how-to-pass-a-javascript-array-via-jquery-post-so-that-all-its-contents-are-acce

Comment: It's generally expected that you show some effort before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

If data in the "myid" field is already a json string, just pass it directly via ajax, with:

```
var myid=$("#myid").val();
$.ajax({
    url:"myurl.php",
    data:myid
});
```