# send javascript array to another php page and get as php array for Processing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

i have an array of object that i created and populated by JavaScript now i want to send it another page where work is performed on that array but in php so any way to get data of javascript array in php like `$phparray = $_Post['javascriptArray'];`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Here is a post that covers it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571646/how-to-pass-a-javascript-array-via-jquery-post-so-that-all-its-contents-are-acce

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to send to php file, for example:

```
  var array = ['1', '2', '3', 'four', 'five'];
  $.ajax({
    url: "/file.php",
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      dataToSend:array
    }
  });
```

and you will receive the array object in php

```
 <? print_r($_POST['dataToSend']?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use javascript cookies or localstorage

Try this tut:
http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html5/localstorage.md.html

Localstorage is only works on  > ie8 & all advance browsers

So u have to use localstorage with Persistance js http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557

Comment: Please provide a code example for the OP. This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Oh yes actually i'm using via mobile so my net is slow thats y i just mention it in short