# Ajax request repeat the same value

Tags: ajax, laravel

I really searched for information more than a week, but I did not find solution. I work with ajax in laravel, my target is get value from post type attachment with ajax . the problem is ajax load only the first value wish I have a foreach loaded all my data on the model.

This work but repeat the same value I have 6 question, but the request just repeat the first , not continue with 2, 3,4 5,6..etc. I want to be better, if you find something wrong with my code, please tell me how to improve. Thank you very much.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/ajax-request-repeat-the-same-value

Comment: please add the (simplified) frontend (JS) and backend (PHP) code to your question.

Comment: the code was on the link

Comment: I  think this link could help you, passing your data as an array to the controller http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571646/how-to-pass-a-javascript-array-via-jquery-post-so-that-all-its-contents-are-acce